# Will making too many transformations "onDrawFrame" create lag?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

I am using the Rajawali framework to make OpenGL ES based live wallpapers. To achieve many of my animation effects I have created some functions that are called from the onDrawFrame method. These functions vary from simple x,y,z rotations to more complicated equations with conditional statements that simulate wind or other randomized motions. It works well currently, and it is highly responsive especially when sleeping and waking the device.

As my live wallpapers become more complex I am worried that my crude solution will eventually start causing performance issues. Is that the case?

Is there a better way to make these types of cyclical or repetitive changes, like maybe making background threads?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move as much computing as posible into vertex and fragment shaders. It's easier to hit other limits than CPU limits. Nobody can answer your question easily without examples and without knowing in depth what are you trying to archive.

Best TIP: Measure often and early during development.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rajawali onDrawFrame() method is called by a timer, which is set with the frameRate() method. This gives much smoother animation than estimating thread sleeps (an alternate solution which is not advised).

If you are at 100fps, this gives you 10ms in between frames to do your calculations - that's it, but that is a lot of time to a modern CPU.

Putting the GPU calculations in a separate thread is problematic since this is not thread safe. You could put any non-GPU calcs in a separate thread, but this could result in sync issues.

Shaders are compiled into native code, but really should be limited to bitwise (integer) operations required to render the actual pixels (always the bottleneck) after all the expensive 3D calcs are done.

For example, an anaglyph shader would take care of overlaying two stereoscopic frames.

Hope this helps!